# Shiro session timeout isn't work

Tags: java, xml, session, shiro

I want my shiro session expire after 1 minutes when a user login the system,but there're some problems that when I login my application first time, everything is ok,but it isn't forward to my login page when i trying to login at the second time after 1 min.Everything is on position in my `applicationContext-shiro.xml`,and I also set the session-timeout in my `web.xml` too.I want some help,thanks anyway.

> applicationContext-shiro.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd"
       default-lazy-init="true">

    <description>Shiro Configuration</description>

    <bean id="sessionIdGenerator" class="org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.JavaUuidSessionIdGenerator"/>

    <bean id="sessionDAO" class="org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.EnterpriseCacheSessionDAO">
        <property name="activeSessionsCacheName" value="shiro-activeSessionCache"/>
        <property name="sessionIdGenerator" ref="sessionIdGenerator"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionValidationScheduler" class="org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.quartz.QuartzSessionValidationScheduler">
        <property name="sessionValidationInterval" value="60000"/>
        <property name="sessionManager" ref="sessionManager"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionManager" class="org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.DefaultSessionManager">
        <property name="globalSessionTimeout" value="60000"/>
        <property name="deleteInvalidSessions" value="true"/>
        <property name="sessionValidationSchedulerEnabled" value="true"/>
        <property name="sessionValidationScheduler" ref="sessionValidationScheduler"/>
        <property name="sessionDAO" ref="sessionDAO"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager">
        <property name="realm" ref="shiroDbRealm"/>
        <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="shiroDbRealm" class="com.aspire.cms.service.impl.ShiroDbRealm">
    </bean>

    <!-- Shiro Filter -->
    <bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
        <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager"/>
        <property name="loginUrl" value="/login"/>
        <property name="successUrl" value="/main"/>
        <!--  <property name="unauthorizedUrl"></property>-->
        <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
            <value>
                /login = authc
                /ajaxLogin = anon
                /logout = logout
                /static/** = anon
                /** = user
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager"/>

    <bean id="lifecycleBeanPostProcessor" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.LifecycleBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator"
          depends-on="lifecycleBeanPostProcessor">
        <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.apache.shiro.spring.security.interceptor.AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor">
        <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

> web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
                xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="migucms" version="2.5">
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            classpath*:/applicationContext-shiro.xml
            classpath*:/applicationContext.xml
           </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:log4j.properties</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
           </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>classpath*:/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
</web-app>
```

> LoginController

```
package com.aspire.cms.controller;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationException;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.IncorrectCredentialsException;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.LockedAccountException;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.UnknownAccountException;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken;
import org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject;
import org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.FormAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    //private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginController.class);
    /** GET  
     * @throws IOException */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        if (SecurityUtils.getSubject().isAuthenticated()) {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/main");
        }

        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView fail(@RequestParam(FormAuthenticationFilter.DEFAULT_USERNAME_PARAM) String userName, String password) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("login");
        mav.addObject(FormAuthenticationFilter.DEFAULT_USERNAME_PARAM, userName);

        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/ajaxLogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Object ajaxLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
                                                @RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password,
                                                @RequestParam boolean rememberMe){

        Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
        String success = "true";
        if (!currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {
            UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(username, password);
            token.setRememberMe(rememberMe);
            try{
                currentUser.login(token);
//              SecurityUtils.getSubject().getSession().setTimeout(60000);
                success = "true";
            } catch(UnknownAccountException ex) {
                success = "1100";
            } catch(IncorrectCredentialsException ex) {
                success = "1101";
            } catch(LockedAccountException ex) {
                success = "1102";
            } catch(AuthenticationException ex) {
                success = "1103";
            }
        }
        //Session session = SecurityUtils.getSubject().getSession(false);
        return success;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/isAuthenticated", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody boolean isAuthenticated() {
        Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
        boolean isAuthenticated = subject.isAuthenticated();

        return isAuthenticated;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add:
`<property name="sessionManager" ref="sessionManager"/>`
to your `securityManager` bean.

Comment: Thanks any way. I tried the way you told but it doesn't work.Should I write any more code to judge if the shiro session was expired?

Comment: Is QuartzSessionValidationScheduler.enableSessionValidation() getting called?  If  you turn on debug logging you should see a log message similar to: 
`Scheduling session validation job using Quartz with ...`

(also make sure you are on the latest Shiro version)